# Internet Speed Sub-Optimal on PC but fine on laptop

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, usb

I built a new PC and have been using a USB wireless adapter for internet access since my router/modem is in a different room. I have 12Mbps service. speedtest.net shows 6-12Mbps for the laptop but the PC never gets above 4.6Mbps. I've tried two USB wireless adapters. Both work fine in the laptop but I always get the slower speeds on the PC.

PC is spyware free and less than a month old.

PC stats:
Windows 7 Ultimate
6 core CPU
8GB RAM
USB Wireless adapter: TP-Link TL-WN321G (54Mbps). At first I was only getting about 1.5Mbps and then I installed the Win7 drivers from the TP-Link website and that's when I started getting 2-4.6Mbps.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the PC and Laptop USB version?